# How to place items list below search input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create custom search input in my html page.

html code:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control"/>
      <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="item in list track by $index">{{item}}</li>
      </ul>
```

and I want the list to be closed always, but to open it only when user clicks on input or changes its value. I want the  element to be fixed below the input, something like this:

[image: list when opened]

but without moving any other element on page.
I **dont** want to add any library but do it myself.

how can I do it by css?

Comment: you forgot the javascript code man, paste it here

Comment: js code is empty. I want to know what to write there, or how to do it without code.

Comment: did you do a proper research before posting this question?

Comment: I tried but dod not find specific answer.

Comment: all you want to do is this: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead

Comment: i hope this fiddle may help you, apologies for bad css . https://jsfiddle.net/3vg7z4h2/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are searching for?

```css
.list-group {
    background-color: white;
    display: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;
}

.list-group > li {
    border-color: gray;
    border-image: none;
    border-style: solid solid none;
    border-width: 1px 1px 0;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

.list-group > li:last-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

.form-control:focus + .list-group {
  display: block; 
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" />
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="item in list track by $index">a) ...</li>
  <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="item in list track by $index">b) ...</li>
  <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="item in list track by $index">c) ...</li>
  <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="item in list track by $index">d) ...</li>
</ul>

<div id="just_a_sample">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut l</div>
```

If yes, just change the css of the `ul`. If you want to move the list to the right, just add some more px to `padding-left`.

---

**EDIT:**

If you want to show the `ul` only if the user clicks in the input, try to use the `+` selector.

See here for more informations: [CSS Selector Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) | [CSS element+element Selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp)

Comment: I think a `ul` has to be a little shifted right about 5-10px and we got a look as Ariela dreamed of.

Comment: @Banzay Thanks. I corrected it.

Comment: @Patrick please see my edit, hope my question now more clear.

Comment: @Ariela I've added some more code. You need js to place the written words inside of your list, if you want to do this.

Comment: @Patrick your solution is working but not perfect, when list opened all other elements move down. I want them to stay in place and list to float over them.

Comment: @Ariela Edited it again. Is this now good?

Comment: @Patrick it's great! working perfect!!! thanks!!!

Comment: @Ariela If this answer solved your problem, please remember to accept this answer and feel free to upvote it.

Comment: of course. sorry i forgot.